# Determining the effect of predictor variables on a binary response

Tags: r, self-study

I'm performing an independent research study and am looking for advice on my approach, and what I can do to improve the study. I'm working in R for this study.

As part of my study I am trying to determine the effect that timing has on patient outcome for elective surgeries. I.e, does the hour, day of week, or month have a significant effect on patient outcome (higher complication rate or higher mortality rate 30 days post op).

My data contains elective surgeries occurring between 6am and 7pm Monday - Friday to assume a single routine shift and schedule. My thought process is that as the hours of the day or days of the week go on, there may be a possibility for fatigue to set in for elective surgeons and this could lead to higher complication rates in patients. Additionally, the 'July Effect' of new residents entering the hospital system could cause a physician to become distracted during a possible procedure.

My current approach is to perform a general linear model:

```
complicationRate ~ hour+DayOfWeek+Month
```

Then depending on the coefficients of these results, I can determine significance. I feel there must be more I can do to strengthen this result, but I'm not exactly sure which topics I should research.

I have a good amount of background in working with R, and am more than willing to research any functions/models I'm not currently familiar with.

Any advice/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Why patient-focused and not doctor focused? At least is true with respect to the frequency of complications. Doctors more rested, more focused, less stressed out,..., could have a .significant impact on rate of complications and quality of results.

Comment: My study is two-fold. The first is determining if the time of a scheduled surgery has an effect on patient outcome (Doctor focused). The second I'm using a series of predictive models to create a model that can predict the likelihood of a complication occurring. These models have the patient underlying health data.